# Is it possible to abort a connection in Bluebird Promisified Request module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, promise, bluebird

I'm working on a project that involving a lot of large files where I only need to extract the `HTTP header` rather than loading the entirely of the file itself, so I'm using the `request` module to extract the HTTP header immediately and then abort the request since I don't need the entirely of the file. Alas, my current structure has me assigning the request object and then using a listener for `response` as such is the case below.

```
const req = request(url);

req.on('response', function(res) {
            if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
                req.abort();
                return this.emit('error', new Error('Bad status code'));
            }
            if (res.headers.hasOwnProperty(headProp)) {
                    parseFunc(res.headers);
                    req.abort();
                }
            });
```

Ideally, I'd like, if possible, to utilize Promises to be able to parse the request URL like:

```
const req = request.getAsync(url)

 req.on('response', function(res) {
     //whatever logic
                });

 req.then(parseFunc(res.headers);
```

But listener events don't really work since the request object hasn't been saved to anything. Additionally, the chained `then` on a `request.getAsync.then` seems to only execute *after* the file has been parsed, which can be 10-11 seconds vs the 250ms-1s of exiting upon the abort.

So, in short: can I get the functionality I desire while avoiding callbacks?

Comment: Sounds like you should be making a [HEAD](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4) request.

Comment: You would have to use the promise constructor manually instead of using promisifyAll and use cancellation but it's entirely possible: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/cancellation.html